# EF4.1 Combobox is databound to navigation properties of an entity, how to save the entity new navigation

Tags: c#, data-binding, entity-framework-4.1

Ok, I have a couple of DataBindingSources pointing to context.[DbSet name].Local.ToBindingList()

there's a datagridview bound to such bindingsource, I have 2 columns set to 2 more databindingsources, thus when changing the values using the comboboxes the parent entity's navigation property changes. So far, so good, now when checking the State by:

```
if(context.Entry(databindingsource.Current).State == EntityState.Modified)
    context.SaveChanges();
```

the State is not Modified but in fact Unchanged, I understand that was intended, and it's not a bug. What I do not understand is how am I suppose to save the changed Navigation property. What is the proper way to go about it? Am I suppose to catch OnChange event from the combobox check the content and set the entity to Modified manually? isn't there a more elegant way?

notes:

- lazyloading is off
- all entities are loaded prior binding everything to datagridview, comboboxes, and textboxes to their relative databindingsources
- all changes are saved when DataBindingSource.CurrentItemChanged event fires
- navigation properties are set to already retrieved entities, /ie entities with Unchanged state/

I'd like to post the code, but it's quite a mess, I believe explaining the problem should suffice. but if not I'm more than willing.

EDIT: the model is generated, DataBase first, database did not include any FK's so all associations are made after the entity generation